# Java Gremlin API traverse in OrientDB

Tags: java, graph, orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have a question about using the Gremlin API with Java in OrientDB.
So, I created a `GremlinPipeline` object, from this pipe object I want to jump to the next vertices:

```
GremlinPipeline pipe = new GremlinPipeline();
pipe.start(graph.getVertex("#18:0"));
pipe.out();
```

Output:

```
v(TokenClass)[#19:0]
v(TokenClass)[#19:1]
v(TokenClass)[#19:2]
```

With this code it returns in my case three vertices, so far perfect. Now I want to traverse for each of this returned vertices again and save each result in a separate List. 
How I can implement this? 
Have I create for each of this vertices an new `GremlinPipeline` object, or is there a nested `GremlinPipeline` function?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: any reason you are using such an old version of OrientDB/TinkerPop? There hasn't be a release of TinkerPop 2.x in years. Any reason not to use https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/tinkerpop3/OrientDB-TinkerPop3.html ?

Comment: Does it implement such a for each function?

Comment: You would just use Gremlin to traverse the graph. `g.V("#18:0").out()` which returns an `Iterator` that you can cycle through the returned vertices in foreach style.

Comment: Yes, but this returns objects from the type `Vertex`. From these vertices I want to traverse again in another directory.

Comment: "directory"? if you want to traverse on out edges again, just do `g.V().out().out()` - here's some more information about the Gremlin language: http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Thx

Comment: @stephenmallette Sorry directory it was a typo, I mean in another direction. You are right, but as I wrote before, I want to save the results for each vertex in a separate list. With your approach I will get only one big list with all results for all vertices.

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi I using OrientDB 2.2.35 and Tinkerpop 2.6

Comment: it's all just Gremlin. `g.V().out().map(out().fold())` or if you want the original vertex you started from you can do `g.V().out().as('a').map(out().fold()).as('b').select('a','b')`. you could also probably do something with `group()` step. unless you have a really solid reason to use an old version of TinkerPop, i'd suggest that you upgrade - the 2.x line is no longer maintained.

Comment: @stephenmallette Oh ok, I think the map operation would be the solution, but how can I use this with java? If I want to use map() my IDE shows me that map wants a String. I use OrientDB for my Bachelor Thesis and I really need the custom Batch insert. In the latest version of the documentation it looks like that they deleted this feature, so I have to use OrientDB 2.2.35. I'm not sure if it is possible to use Tinkerpop 3.x with this OrientDB version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was misunderstanding on my site. The `GremlinPipeline` returns `Vertex` objects. The crunchpoint is, if we want to start a new `GremlinPipeline` we only need one of the  returned vertices, so we don't need to make a new call to OrientDB to retrieve the wanted vertex. We have already `Vertex` objects to start a new `GremlinPipeline`. For example, it looks like this:

```
GremlinPipeline pipe = new GremlinPipeline();

pipe.start(graph.getVertex("#18:0"));
pipe.out();

List<Vertex> currentTokenList = pipe.toList();
for (Vertex currentToken : currentTokenList) { //with the currentToken we can start a new GremlinPipeline
    System.out.println("aktuelles Token " + currentToken);
    GremlinPipeline pipe2 = new GremlinPipeline();
    pipe2.start(currentToken);
    pipe2.out();
    List<Vertex> currentRIDList = pipe2.toList();
    for (Vertex ridVertex : currentRIDList) {
        System.out.println(ridVertex);
    }
}
```